# Retrieving objects from a HashMap using java

Tags: java, enums, dictionary

Suppose that you have:

```
Map<something of enum type, Object>;
```

If you know the enum, how do you gain access to the ObjecT?

Comment: What do you mean by "know the enum"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For enums it works the same way as for maps in general:

```
Object value = map.get(enumKey);
```

Note that with enum keys, it is recommended to use an [`EnumMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) instead of `HashMap`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`get`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
Object result = map.get(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Enums are objects in java.  As such, they can be used as keys in the get method.

Comment: Actually, I forgot about EnumMap.  Probably better to follow Peter's suggestion.